# unordered set, it it worth calling find before insert?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

When inserting elements into an std::unorder_set is it worth calling std::unordered_set::find prior to std::unordered_set::insert? From my understanding, I should always just call insert as it returns an std::pair which contains a bool that tells whether the insertion succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `find` before `insert` is essentially an anti-pattern, which is typically observed in poorly designed custom set implementations. Namely, it might be necessary in implementations that do not tell the caller whether the insertion actually occurred. `std::set` does provide you with this information, meaning that it is normally not necessary to perform this *find-before-insert* dance.

A typical implementation of `insert` will typically contain the full implementation of `find`, meaning that the *find-before-insert* approach performs the search twice for no meaningful reason.

However, some other shortcomings of `std::set` design do sometimes call for a *find-before-insert* sequence. For example, if your set elements contain some fields that need to be modified if (an only if) the actual insertion occurred. For example, you might have to allocate "permanent" memory for some pointer fields instead of "temporary" (local) memory these fields were pointing to before the insertion. Unfortunately, this is impossible to do *after* the insertion, since `std::set` only provides you with non-modifying access to its elements. One workaround is to do a `find` first, thus "predicting" whether an actual insertion will occur, and then setting up the new element accordingly (like allocating "permanent" memory for all fields) *before* doing the `insert`. This is ugly from the performance point of view, but it is acceptable in non-performance-critical code. That's just how things are with standard containers.

Comment: "modified if (an only if) the actual insertion occurred" - pretty elaborate scenario.  FWIW, making such fields `mutable` (reasonable if they're `private`) or casting away `const` (hackish / perhaps from a member function dedicated to the transmogrification) are other performant options - they mustn't change the order relative to other `set` members - or for this question's `unordered_set` the hash value and equality - but then if the change did so a prior `find` would be broken too (but likely with less disastrous consequences). (+1)

Answer (score 1):

It's best to just attempt the insert, otherwise the effort of hashing and iterating over any elements that have collided in the hash bucket is unnecessarily repeated.

Answer (score 1):

If your set it threadsafe and accessed concurrently then calling `find` first does very little, as `insert` would be atomic but a check-then-act would be susceptible to race condition.

So in general and especially in a multithreaded context, just insert.